# Как передавать информацию о пользователях вместе с их аватаркой с node.js на react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

У меня в базе хранится информация о пользователях и путь к их аватарке.
Допустим такая модель:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    birthday: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Получаю из базы и отдаю данные на react я таким образом:

```
exports.getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const users = await User.find();
        res.status(200).json({
            users: users
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res
            .status(500)
            .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Server error.' }] });
    }
};
```

Как мне вместо строки, в которой содержится путь до картинки, отдавать саму картинку и каким образом ее возможно выводить в react?

Comment: Мне кажется лучше использовать  не путь до картинку а `url`, тогда и отобразить не составит труда.

Comment: А в чем проблема отобразить картинку, указав источник? К примеру так: `<img src={"./image.jpeg"} />`, где `src` - путь к графическому файлу. Отдавая саму картинку - повысится размер сообщения, а значит и производительность упадет, а потом и вовсе упретесь в максимальный размер сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

Отказалась от идеи передавать картинки, отдаю путь, а на фронте подгружаю картинку по ссылке.
В серверной части для роутинга использовала app.use(express.static('public'));